# The attribute 'onclick' may not appear in tag 'a'

Tags: amp-html

The attribute 'onclick' may not appear in tag 'a'.

```
<ul class="social-icons circle inheritMargin">
                                        <li><a  class="pull-left"  href="#" onclick="shareOnTwitter(1)" ><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a  class="pull-right" onclick="myFunction2(this)"  href="#" ><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
```

Comment: in place of onclick on tap work in amp, AMP does not support custom javascript

Comment: You need to try looking for custom elements in ampdocumentation

Answer (score 0):

As others commented, AMP does not permit JavaScript on the page (except for the experimental `<amp-script>` component, but that is not relevant here). So instead of using "onclick", you use the AMP "on" attribute instead. See https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events for more details. Look for things like `on="tap:..."`.

Note that because you cannot use JavaScript, you have to achieve what the JavaScript is trying to do in a different way. This frequently involves using AMP state instead of JavaScript and the AMP bind support to update attributes in the DOM. That is, the "on" attribute is not a drop in replacement for "onclick" - you need to work out how to achieve the same effect as the JavaScript using AMP.